# Is good reduction decidable?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lo.logic, arithmetic-geometry, computability-theory, computer-science

Let $X$ be a smooth projective geometrically connected variety over $\mathbb{Q}$. It is said to have good reduction at a prime $p$ is there is a smooth projective $\mathcal{X}\to \mathrm{Spec}\:\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ with $\mathcal{X}_{\mathbb{Q}}\approx X$.

If I understand correctly, to say that $X$ has good reduction at $p$ is naively a $\Sigma^0_2$-statement. Gro-Tsen's answer shows it can in fact be decided by a halting oracle for ordinary Turing machines. Can it be decided by an ordinary Turing machine?

Comment: In the case of abelian varieties, by Neron-ogg-shafarevich, it is a $\Pi_1^0$ statement if I understand correctly.

Comment: -1 for changing the question after it received a complete answer

Answer (score 8):

Consider a Turing machine which enumerates all possible projective $\mathcal{X} \to \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$, all possible morphisms $\varphi\colon X \to \mathcal{X}_\eta$ (where $\mathcal{X}_\eta$ is the generic fiber) and all possible morphisms $\psi\colon \mathcal{X}_\eta \to X$, and, for each $(\mathcal{X},\varphi,\psi)$, checks whether $\mathcal{X}$ is in fact smooth, and $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are inverse to each other: if so, it halts, otherwise, it proceeds to the next candidate.  This machine stops iff $X$ has good reduction at $p$, so this can be decided using the halting oracle (for ordinary Turing machines), i.e., “$X$ has good reduction at $p$” is, in fact (equivalent to) a $\Sigma^0_1$ statement of arithmetic (namely the statement that the machine just described halts).

Comment: Is it obvious that all those collections are enumerable?

Comment: I think so. We have to iterate over possible dimensions and for each dimension, the base ring is countable so there are countably many projective schemes and given $X_\eta,X$, morphism between them are another countable family.

Comment: @LSpice Well, yes and no. Once it is checked that these various algebraico-geometric objects can be represented by finitistic data that can be manipulated by a Turing machine, it's straightforward to just enumerate all possible such data. What isn't obvious is that they can indeed be represented (well, for $\mathscr{X}$ it is by the definition of “projective”). For this, see §16 of [my joint paper with F. Orgogozo](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ant/1510842393) (not claiming originality here, it was probably considered folklore).

Comment: @Asvin Right, although the emphasis isn't so much on “countable” (although this is certainly a prerequisite) as on the fact that the relevant data (schemes, morphisms between them, etc.) can be indeed represented by computer.